# How do I make a rich menu for an appindicator?

Tags: indicator, python, application-development, pygtk

I'm adding menu items to an appindicator in pygtk. I don't want them to behave like ordinary menu items: I want them to have normal appearance, but not to respond to mouse hovers and mouse clicks. The way I imagine [the new sound menu will behave](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/some-natty-sound-menu-updates/).

In other words, I want to prevent the MenuItem selection that's going on below:

[image]

How do I go about doing that? What events should I swallow, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, appindicator doesn't allow adding custom widget, as it requires GObject introspection. This will be available when `ido` package will have GObject instrospection.

[Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ido/+bug/582985)

Comment: I've been able to add alignments, labels, and images; as well as listen for (some) signals on those items.

Answer (score 8):

What I've done for [StackApplet](https://launchpad.net/stackapplet) is to simply disable a menu item and use that as a 'header'. That way it doesn't respond to mouse clicks and looks like a static text label.

[image]