# how to keep the app indicator menu visible after clicks?

Tags: application-development, pygtk, appindicator

I have a specific need in which I want app indicator menu item to respond to mouse click but menu should not disappear, for example when I click play in music menu, menu does not disappear, can i also implement similar thing in indicator menu?

Reference : [How do I make a rich menu for an appindicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26908/how-do-i-make-a-rich-menu-for-an-appindicator?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately at this time you can only use standard menu items in the application indicators.  All of the standard menu items cause the menu to close, where the one in the sound menu is a custom item that avoids that.  We plan in the future to provide the ability to use custom menu items to application indicators, but that work is not yet complete.